# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'BitVector'

Tags: python, nonetype, bitvector

here is the python code.

```
from BitVector import *
MX = BitVector(bitstring = '00011011')
MSB_check = BitVector(bitstring = '10000000')

def multiplication_logic(num):
   num = num.shift_left(1) # left shift
   MSB_num = num & MSB_check # AND num with 1000 0000 to get only MSB
   if MSB_num.intValue() != 0:
      num = num ^ MX #XOR with 00011011
   return num

for indexOfOneInPoly2 in range (0,7):
   if polynomial_2[indexOfOneInPoly2] == 1 and indexOfOneInPoly2 != 0:
      for numberOfIndexTimes in range (0,indexOfOneInPoly2):
         temp = multiplication_logic(polynomial_1)
         print(temp)
   polynomial_3 = polynomial_3 + temp
print(polynomial_3)
```

For the above code I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#126>", line 4, in <module>
    temp = multiplication_logic(polynomial_1)
  File "<pyshell#124>", line 3, in multiplication_logic
    MSB_num = num & MSB_check 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'BitVector'
```

How can I make my function take parameter as a BitVector (since this is what i think is creating the problem

Comment: `num.shift_left(1)` is returning `None`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `BitVector.shift_left()` method returns `None`, presumably because the bit vector is mutated *in place*.

There is no need to re-assign `num` in this case, just use:

```
def multiplication_logic(num):
   num.shift_left(1)
   MSB_num = num & MSB_check # AND num with 1000 0000 to get only MSB
   if MSB_num != 0:
      num = num ^ MX #XOR with 00011011
   return num
```

If you are using the [`BitVector` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BitVector) you'll need to upgrade to version 3.1 or newer (current release is 3.4.4), as that release added `return self` to the `BitVector.shift_left()` and `BitVector.shift_right()` methods.

From the project changelog:

> Version 3.1:
>
> This version includes: [....] (3) The non-circular bit shift methods now return self so that they can be chained;